# MySQL Errno 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a few simple tables and I can't get passed this foreign key error and I'm not sure why. Here's the script below.

```
create TABLE Instructors (

ID varchar(10),
First_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Last_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

create table Courses (

Course_Code varchar(10),
Title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Course_Code)

);


create table Sections (
Index_No int,
Course_Code varchar(10),
Instructor_ID varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (Index_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Course_Code) REFERENCES Courses(Course_Code)
    ON DELETE cascade
    ON UPDATE cascade,
FOREIGN KEY (Instructor_ID) REFERENCES Instructors(ID)
    ON DELETE set default

);
```

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table '336_project.sections' (errno: 150)

My data types seem identical and the syntax seems correct. Can anyone point out what I'm not seeing here?

I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using the InnoDB engine, the `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` is your problem. Here's an excerpt from the manual:

> > While SET DEFAULT is allowed by the MySQL Server, it is rejected as invalid by InnoDB. CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements using this clause are not allowed for InnoDB tables.

You can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL`, but not `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`. There's more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I tried changing to SET NULL and it still doesn't work. I even removed all of the ON UPDATE/DELETE lines and still gives me the error. Should I be specifying a particular engine to use?

Comment: Disregard the last comment, I fixed it. You were right, I had to change the default to null, but also I had create indexes for each foreign key reference. Once i did that, it worked!

Comment: @Sixers17 - just so you know, when I tried your `CREATE TABLE` statements here, the only thing I had to do to make them work was the change to `ON DELETE SET NULL`. I didn't have to add indexes. That said, it's a good idea to have indexes along your FKs anyway so all's well :)

Comment: Hm interesting, I wonder why mine doesn't work without indexes.

Comment: I notice you can't set the column to `NOT NULL` either. Discovered migrating an `ON DELETE RESTRICT` column to an `ON DELETE SET NULL` column.

Answer (score 35):

This error also occurs if you are relating columns of different types, eg. int in the source table and BigInt in the destination table.

Comment: or the referenced table has not InnoDB engine

Comment: This was my issue. I am using Laravel and my parent column was an "increments" column. I had to change my reference column to an unsignedInteger.

Answer (score 20):

You can run

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

to read the reason of the failure in a human readable format

e.g.

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
150331 15:51:01 Error in foreign key constraint of table foobar/#sql-413_81:
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `foobar`.`users`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE:
You have defined a SET NULL condition though some of the columns are defined as NOT NULL.
```

Comment: This is treasure! This helps diagnose other issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

In order to create a `FOREIGN KEY` with reference to another table, the keys from both tables should be `PRIMARY KEY` and with the same datatype.

In your table sections, `PRIMARY KEY` is of different datatype i.e `INT` but in another table, it's of type i.e `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 3):

It may also be the case if you are not specifying the `ON DELETE` at all but are trying to reference a MYISAM table from InnoDB table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM CHARACTER SET UTF8;

CREATE TABLE `table2`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table1_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `some_value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,


    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_table1_id`(`table1_id`),

    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1`(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

The above will throw *errno 150*. One need to change the first table to InnoDB too for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing on the

```
ON DELETE set default
```

I have not come across that before and I am not seeing it in the manuals either ( but then it is late )

**Update**

just seen this in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> While SET DEFAULT is allowed by the MySQL Server, it is rejected as
>   invalid by InnoDB. CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements using this
>   clause are not allowed for InnoDB tables.

I guess you may be using InnoDB tables ?

Comment: Should I be putting Engine=InnoDB after table declarations?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake - you will also get this error if you make a foreign reference to a table that isn't defined at the time;

Answer (score 0):

Here Problem is in database engine ( table1 `MYISAM` and table2  `ENGINE`).
To set FOREIGN KEYs,

- Both table must be in same ENGINE and same charset.
- PK column in parent and FK column must be in same data type and same collation type.

Hope you got an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that table type is InnoDB, MyISAM does not support foreign key, afaik.