# MySql error 150, don't know why

Tags: mysql, database

I created to 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Albums_On_Facebook` (
  `Album_Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Facebook_Album_Id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Open_Time` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Album open time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Album_Id`,`Facebook_Album_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Album_Id_Onfacebook-Fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`Album_Id`) REFERENCES `Albums` (`Album_Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Pictures_In_Album` (
  `Facebook_Album_Id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Faceook_Picture_Id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Time_Taken` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time that the photo was taken',
  `Description` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COMMENT 'caption of the photo',
  `Source` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL COMMENT 'Source of the photo',
  `Latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Location of where the photo was taken',
  `Longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Location of where the photo was taken',
  `Is_Best_Picture` bit(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Best picture or not',
  `Photographer_Facebook_Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Facebook identity of the user',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Facebook_Album_Id`,`Faceook_Picture_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i'm trying to add this contraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `Pictures_In_Album`
ADD CONSTRAINT Facebook_Album_Id_PicInAlbum_fKey
FOREIGN KEY (`Facebook_Album_Id`)
REFERENCES `Albums_On_Facebook`(`Facebook_Album_Id`);
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Can't create table 'PicoNew.#sql-1cc8_6d29' (errno: 150)

Why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227199/mysql-errno-150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a key in your `Albums_On_Facebook` table for the referenced column. This column is secondary of your PRIMARY KEY. That is not enough:

> [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

[...]

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.
>
> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. **However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.** (emphasis by me)