# Issue when trying to create table for many to many relationship mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table for a `many to many` relationship in `mySQL`. This is the `sql` for it:

```
CREATE TABLE `directoryprogrammetags` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `directoryprogramme_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT,
  `created` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`directoryprogramme_id`) REFERENCES directoryprogramme(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES tag(id) 
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1005
Can't create table 'mytestdatabase.directoryprogrammetags' (errno: 150)
```

The tables that the foreign keys reference are:

```
CREATE TABLE `directoryprogramme` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I read somewhere that it could be to do with an inconsistency with the foreign key but I am not sure. Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227199/mysql-errno-150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the `directoryprogramme` table that you are referencing was created using a different engine (MyISAM) than the rest of the tables (InnoDB). If you change the engine so it uses the same one then the error goes away:

```
CREATE TABLE `directoryprogramme` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
         ^^^^^ This is the difference
```

You can check in [**this sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/866cf) that it works when you use this code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use foreign keys from InnoDB to MyISAM.   Change the database engine on `directoryprogramme` to InnoDB, and I bet it'll work.